# How to remove the header border bottom of the Drawer component in blueprintjs?

Tags: css, reactjs, blueprint

I want to remove/change the styling of the border bottom of the header shown bellow:

[image: Drawer header]

But even when I set the border: none for the class bp3-drawer-header it is still there. It seems it's not even a border, since it doesn't appear here when I inspect:

[image: Drawer header inspect]

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check for box-shadow. it's also could be.And also check for parents elements and child which contains all elements in your header section. You should find border or box-shadow.